# Searching SQL server 2005 for string value across all tables get table name in addition to record

Tags: sql-server

Found this on Server Fault:

> I've found this script to be helpful...

```
BEGIN TRAN

declare @search nvarchar(100)
set @search = 'string to search for'

-- search whole database for text
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

IF nullif(object_id('tempdb..#tmpSearch'), 0) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpSearch
CREATE TABLE #tmpSearch (
    ListIndex int identity(1,1),
    CustomSQL nvarchar(2000)
)
Print 'Getting tables...'
INSERT #tmpSearch (CustomSQL)
select 'IF EXISTS (select * FROM [' + TABLE_NAME + '] WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''%' + @search + '%'') BEGIN PRINT ''Table ' + TABLE_NAME + ', Column ' + COLUMN_NAME + ''';select * FROM [' + TABLE_NAME + '] WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''%' + @search + '%'' END'  FROM information_schema.columns
where DATA_TYPE IN ('ntext', 'nvarchar', 'uniqueidentifier', 'char', 'varchar', 'text')
and TABLE_NAME NOT IN ('table_you_dont_want_to_look_in', 'and_another_one') 


Print 'Searching...

'
declare @index int
declare @customsql nvarchar(2000)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpSearch)
BEGIN
    SELECT @index = min(ListIndex) FROM #tmpSearch

    SELECT @customSQL = CustomSQL FROM #tmpSearch WHERE ListIndex = @index

    IF @customSql IS NOT NULL
        EXECUTE (@customSql)

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DELETE #tmpSearch WHERE ListIndex = @index
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END

print 'the end.'
ROLLBACK
```

But I'm curious how I could modify this script to also give the table name, as it only returns the record(s) with the search string....

Wasn't able to comment on the original answer due to 1 Rep on that version of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages section of the output window will print the table names.

Answer (score 1):

Change your SELECT to include it:

```
INSERT #tmpSearch (CustomSQL)
select 'IF EXISTS (select * FROM [' + TABLE_NAME + '] WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''%' + @search + '%'') BEGIN PRINT ''Table ' + TABLE_NAME + ', Column ' + COLUMN_NAME + ''';select *, [' + TABLE_NAME + '] AS TABLE_NAME FROM [' + TABLE_NAME + '] WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] LIKE ''%' + @search + '%'' END'  FROM information_schema.columns
where DATA_TYPE IN ('ntext', 'nvarchar', 'uniqueidentifier', 'char', 'varchar', 'text')
and TABLE_NAME NOT IN ('table_you_dont_want_to_look_in', 'and_another_one')
```